# Path to inline image <img> inside page.tpl.php to theme/images/ dir?

Tags: 7, media, theming

Simply  pasted to page.tpl.php doesn't work. It doesn't find the image and requires full path.

I know I've seen somewhere some PHP code which sets full path to image inside the theme's dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get you the path to your theme, together with your site's base path:

```
<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>
```

Meaning that you should use something like this:

```
<img src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>/images/your-image.jpg">
```

*Note:* the `path_to_theme()` will not have the trailing slash, so you have to add it yourself if your image is in a subfolder.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found a solution myself already. I used <img src="<?php print(drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_name'));?>/images/image.png" />

Comment: Isn't the `print` supposed to be inside the `<img>` tag?

Comment: In that case, post the solution and accept is as an answer. It will be useful for other people that have the same issue as you do.

Comment: Yes same as the one posted by @user13176

Comment: @Indrock this gives only image path - it should be used in `src=""` attribute.

Comment: @Topsitemakers Yeah, I'm aware of that! But, I think it'd be spot on if you mention it in you post. That would make it complete ;-)

Comment: Answer updated!